Re-login required every time I restart my Windows computer since fresh install
So I re-installed Windows 11 in the beginning of the year. Fresh and clean. Ever since I have the issue, that:

Office Apps tell me they couldn't sync as there's an issue with my account I need to fix
Xbox App tells me there's an issue with my account I need to fix with the message "a recent change in your machine requires you to sign in again"

But oddly enough OneDrive for example works fine. The odd thing is I only need to enter my e-mail on the login screen, then it immediately signs me in again and everything is working (might need to restart the app).
Anyone has a clue what causes this? It's hella annoying.
Only thing I can think of that might be a reason is: I also added my work account as such. But as far as I remember I did not allow it to control my PCs settings. Just so I can access my company Outlook stuff.
If anyone has an idea, I'd be glad to hear it!

If your work account has the same email address as your private account, then it will get confused what account you used, and will use the wrong password.

It is not the same mail address, no. Thing is I see no option to remove my private account as I'd imagine readding it might help...
